# Password Expiry Date using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory

i want to display the password expiry dialogbox using c++ win32 API...

i done it using System.directoryservice namespace...

But now i need in Win32 API..

Any functions there for get password expiry date?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function to get the password expiration date:

```
HRESULT GetPasswordExpirationDate(LPTSTR lpszPathName, LPSYSTEMTIME lpExpirationDate)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IADsUser *pUser;
    hr = ADsGetObject(lpszPathName, IID_IADsUser, (void**) &pUser);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DATE expirationDate;
        hr = pUser->get_PasswordExpirationDate(&expirationDate);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            VariantTimeToSystemTime(expirationDate, lpExpirationDate);

        pUser->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Where `lpszPathName`is a [LDAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [WinNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) path and `lpExpirationDate` is a pointer to [`SYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Note, that you must include `Windows.h`, `Iads.h` and `Adshlp.h` and link with `ADSIid.Lib` and `ActiveDS.Lib` to get it work.

Example usage:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

SYSTEMTIME expirationDate;
HRESULT hr = GetPasswordExpirationDate(_T("WinNT://ComputerName/UserName,user"),
    &expirationDate);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //TODO: do whatever you want with the expirationDate here
}

CoUninitialize();
```

You may want to use one of the following API calls to retrieve current user and computer/domain names: [`GetUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`GetComputerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [`GetUserNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`NetWkstaUserGetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you need to retrieve password expiration dates for multiple domain users, it might be better to use [`ADsBuildEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [`ADsGetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see example on MSDN).

Comment: @Nikole:i cant get the `get_PasswordExpirationDate();` i also use ADSI functions,but i can't get the above function only...**how i can get this function**? i also see this example in a site...but `get_PasswordExpirationDate();`these function only make a problem...

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what do you mean. But I suspect you just forgot to query [`IADsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746340(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. E.g.: `pADs->QueryInterface(IID_IADsUser, (void**) &pUser);` PS: I'm Nikolay. Nikole is a female name.

Comment: Sorry for spelling mistake Nikolay...my code part is,`'IADs * pIADsrootDSE = NULL; _BSTR(&var) = SysAllocString(L"No"); V_VT(&var) = VT_BSTR;           hr = pIADsrootDSE->Put(L"BiometricStatus",var );
 hr = pIADsrootDSE->SetInfo();'` these code works...but i am using `'hr = pIADsrootDSE->get_PasswordExpirationDate(&expirationDate);'` the following error occured...error C2039: 'get_PasswordExpirationDate' : is not a member of 'IADs'` Now got it?

Comment: @SanjuMonu Well. Firsly, `pIADsrootDSE` is [`IADs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705950(v=vs.85).aspx) and doesn't support `PasswordExpirationDate`. As I said before, you must use [`IADsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746340(v=vs.85).aspx). You can get it by calling either [`ADsGetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772184(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @SanjuMonu Your next problem is that `pIADsrootDSE` seems to be a [Root DSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684291(v=vs.85).aspx). So you can't just use `QueryInterface` on it. And finally, `pIADsrootDSE` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Nikolay...i tried,what u said,but i cant get the value...`hr = pUser->get_PasswordExpirationDate(&expirationDate);`...hr gives -2147463155 value not S_OK...and i checked `hr = pUser->get_PasswordLastChanged(&expirationDate);`...it gives success(S_OK)...**so what's a problem in that function?**

Comment: Take a look at [ADSI/LDAP error: "-2147463155 (8000500d)"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243440)

Comment: @ Nikolay...thanks for the link...but i cant get whats an issue for my code... **Any other way 2 achieve password expirydate?**